# clickonce update choice

Tags: clickonce

I have a clickonce install that works fine. However, if I set an update strategy when defining the clickonce manifest, the applications gets updated based on that rule and they never have the choice to postpone the update.

How can I give the user the choice to update or not the application ?

EDIT 24/10/2011 following codeConcussion's questions: 
The update is defined so that:
- the application should check for updates
- before the application starts

However I'd rather propose a suggestion to update, with the final decision to be made by the end-user (like in windows update) rather than impose the update in all cases.

Comment: Can you clarify "...I set an update strategy when defining the clickonce manifest...". What are you setting it to? Before the app starts? After the app starts? Every time it runs? Every x days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it check for updates before running the application in the Updates dialog. If you do not set the minimum required version, it will prompt the user for the update, and give them the opportunity to skip or accept the update.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a boostrap for it, where you it will pop up your custom made screen and ask if they want to go ahead with your update or not.

Comment: does that mean there is no possibility to do that within clickonce directly ?

Comment: Yes, as noted in my response -- just don't make it a required update, and it will ask the user if he wants to Skip it or go ahead and install it.